# Changing the Constraints Programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Ready For"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarExercise"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/readyflProgressBar"
    />
```

I want to change the constraints of this `TextView` programatically through kotlin. How do I do that?

Comment: if your textview constraints depends other layout components visibility you can use barrier.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand

Comment: What's your condition?

Answer (score 0):

> This Works For Me

In My Xml :

```
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
```

java

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
     ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
     constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
     constraintSet.connect(R.id.otherView,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.view1,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
     constraintSet.connect(R.id.otherView,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.view1,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
     constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```